# segfault-handler@1.3.0 on WSL2

Tags: node.js, wsl-2

Hello is there any advice to get segfault-handler@1.3.0 running on WSL2?

We are using pnpm: (current: {"node":"v14.15.1","pnpm":"7.13.5"})

Is there an architecture specific build/rebuild for example?

This package load successfully a VM in ubuntu directly but not if run via WSL2

The error in the logs:

```
Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Debug/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/out/Debug/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/Debug/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/out/Release/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/Release/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/default/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/compiled/14.15.1/linux/x64/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/addon-build/release/install-root/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/addon-build/debug/install-root/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/addon-build/default/install-root/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|  → /home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/segfault-handler.node
3|myapp|     at bindings (/home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/bindings@1.5.0/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:126:9)
3|myapp|     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<appbase>/node_modules/.pnpm/segfault-handler@1.3.0/node_modules/segfault-handler/index.js:3:37)
3|myapp|     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
3|myapp|     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
3|myapp|     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
3|myapp|     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
3|myapp|     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
3|myapp|     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
3|myapp|     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<appbase>/apps/surgical-partners-executor/index.js:7:23)
3|myapp|     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
3|myapp|     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
3|myapp|     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
3|myapp|     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
3|myapp|     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
3|myapp|     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
3|myapp|   tries: [
```

Comment: "This works on a VM in ubuntu directly" _What_ works? You're going to have to explain things a bit more in depth: how did you install things? And what did you set up and then run to get this output? And what did you already do as mitigation attempts?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the help. I have updated the post. Basically if we run this package in our node application it crashes in the log in WSL2. If we however use the same ubuntu version in a VM. This package runs with no issues. 
This makes me this there is some architecture or build issue when the process is hosted under WSL
The workaround at the moment is to comment out this package and the app runs successfully.

Comment: Don't tell "me": [edit] your post so that everyone reading your post gets [all the details in the post itself](/help/how-to-ask). (And not by writing: "edit: ...", edit the post so that anyone reading it gets the details in the order they make sense in).

Comment: No, you didn't. Explain how you set this up: did you copy the files or actually install them? _How_ are you installing things? What do folks need to do to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans We are using pnpm: (current: {"node":"v14.15.1","pnpm":"7.13.5"}) the version of the library is in the post. I am reaching out to anyone who has experienced this issue and has either solved the problem or has a workaround. It's obscure .. but specifically, I would like to think this is not an issue with the library. But the way node binds under WSL is different to the OS running natively.

Comment: It might be obscure, but you should be able to form an [mcve] and put that [in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Plenty of Windows folks using WSL2 who should be able to reproduce your problem if you give them steps for that, so they can properly see what you're talking about, and use your MCVE as reference for how to get things working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my own answer to this problem.

After confirming the get started code fails oob with npm.

As we are using node 14. I found we needed to use node:lts/fermium .

Next still needed to npm rebuild.

Also found it also works with pnpm too, just use lts/fermium and npm rebuild <-- that seems important as WSL2 is a different arch.

https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler/issues/87